# Sylius - How to implement a custom EntityRepository

Tags: sylius

I'm getting a bit frustrated trying to override the repository of my own Entity.

I need to create a custom repository method to get a list of my entities with special way. One queryBuilder with `Having` and `OrderBy`.

Te question is how can I setup my config to say Sylius, take my custom repositor, not the default.

I try this:

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        dinamic.category:
            classes:
                model: App\Bundle\SyliusBlogBundle\Entity\PostCategory
                repository: App\Bundle\SyliusBlogBundle\Repository\PostCategoryRepository
```

This is my Repository:

```
<?php

namespace App\Bundle\SyliusBlogBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PostCategoryRepository extends EntityRepository 
{
   public function findCategoriesMenu()
   {
      $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
      return $queryBuilder
        ->addSelect('COUNT(p.id) as totalPosts')
        ->leftJoin('c.posts', 'p')
        ->andWhere('p.published = true')
        ->having('totalPosts > 0')
        ->addGroupBy('p.id')
        ;
    }
}
```

When I try to use this method, Symfony throws me this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Undefined method 'findCategoriesMenu'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you aren't subclassing the correct repository. The `ResourceController` expects a repository based on the `Sylius\Component\Resource\Repository\RepositoryInterface`. Since you are subclassing from `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` that won't be the case.

Your repository should inherit from `Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` (or implement the interface yourself).

Comment: You're right Steffen! It works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I answer to the post to paste correctly the response of `app/console debug:container dinamic.repository.category`

```
Information for Service "dinamic.repository.category"
=====================================================

 ------------------ -------------------------------------------------------------------
  Option             Value
 ------------------ -------------------------------------------------------------------
  Service ID         dinamic.repository.category
  Class              Dinamic\Bundle\SyliusBlogBundle\Repository\PostCategoryRepository
  Tags               -
  Scope              container
  Public             yes
  Synthetic          no
  Lazy               no
  Synchronized       no
  Abstract           no
  Autowired          no
  Autowiring Types   -
 ------------------ -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Since here all it's ok.

When i try to access to Posts list this error appears:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController::__construct() must implement interface Sylius\Component\Resource\Repository\RepositoryInterface, instance of Dinamic\Bundle\SyliusBlogBundle\Repository\PostCategoryRepository given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rosasinbox-sylius/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2767 and defined")

The error of main post appears when the repository config wasn't set. Then my first post was wrong, on `config.yml` repository value wasn't set.

Now i set it another time and i got this error.

## Sorry for the confusion.